# Etale maps and local intersection cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, intersection-cohomology

Suppose that $f:(X,x) \to (Y,y)$ is etale at $x$, meaning that it induces an isomorphism $C_xX \to C_yY$ on tangent cones.  Then $f$ induces an isomorphism from the cohomology of $IC_{X,x}$ (the stalk of the IC sheaf at x) to the cohomology of $IC_{Y,y}$.

Now suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two such maps, inducing two different isomorphisms from $H^*(IC_{X,x})$ to $H^*(IC_{Y,y})$.

Question:  If $f$ and $g$ induce the same isomorphism on tangent cones, does it follow that $f$ and $g$ induce the same isomorphism from $H^*(IC_{X,x})$ to $H^*(IC_{Y,y})$?